# new IP different gateway

Tags: debian

well I am noob and I'm trying to fix this issue without luck.
I had an old VPS for 2 years and today I requested an additional IP, I noticed the new IP is out range for current old gateway. I used the old way to add the new IP but it didn't work, I can only ping the new IP from the VPS but not from outside.
Here is my current configuration

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 37.187.183.xx
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 37.187.183.254

auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
        address 37.187.203.xx
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```